# what does nanosleep with zero time value do?

Tags: c, libc

What will this code do?

```
struct timespec wait;
wait.tv_sec = 0;
wait.tv_nsec = 0;
nanosleep(&wait, NULL);
```

or

```
 ...
 clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, &wait, NULL);
```

Will it be optimized away? or the process simply preempted and immediately put back to the run queue? or what?

any difference between using nanosleep and clock_nanosleep, with exactly the parameters given here?

Answer (score 0):

Whether the thread will actually be suspended for any length of time does not appear to be guaranteed.  If specific behavior is required, it would be best to either bypass the call or use a value other than `0`.

Comment: I presume it might cause a context switch. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html

Comment: @KeithThompson: Agreed.  My point was just that it doesn't seem to guaranteed.  I'll try to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

> Will it be optimized away?

No, it can't be reliably reduced to a nop.

> or the process simply preempted and immediately put back to the run
>   queue?

Well yes, for certain values of "immediately". It does not look like there's any kind of short-path for zero timeout, so it will be re-scheduled just like any other expired timeout.

> any difference between using nanosleep and clock_nanosleep, with exactly the parameters given here?

None as per nanosleep(2).